# I can't always call the function until I change or delete the name that is between parentheses

Tags: javascript, function

i have 3 question about this code:

The task was to make a black border around the photo, but with the **help of 2 functions**

**1.** The name of the function that is inside the parentheses can contain part of the name of the function that is outside the parentheses.
   the word ***(set)*** e.g.:
   **function setBlackColor (setBcol)**
because it reports an error if I write [ ***(set)*** ]as I mentioned before.

but when I write like this: **black(as);** it *will work.*
**instead of**: function setBlackColor (setBcol).// *here erorr*

**2.** when I use this **function "border (setBorder);"** calls in for loop, then the program reports an error until I **delete** the word **between the brackets** it will work.
But **if I change** the *word* to another word, it **won't** work.

**q:** what's the problem here**?**

**3.** what is the **assignment** of name between brackets in functions name e.g.: (**bC**)
function blackColor (bC)?

how can you use this(bC)in my code and why?

```
// write your code here
[editor mit der Quelle der Fotos ][1]
//
photo
var img= new SimpleImage("smallpanda.png");
img.setSize(200,200);
print(img);

// function to make black color
function  black(as){
    pixel.setRed(20);
    pixel.setGreen(20);
    pixel.setBlue(0);

}


    // function to define the black border of the photo and then the function (black) must be called to 
   // color the border with black 

    function border(){


        // the first line of border above
        if((x<w/1) && (y<h/20)){
      black(as);

        }


        //the second left line of the border
        if((x<w/20) && (y<h/1)){
        // the function with the name 
         black(as);
        }


        //right border
         if((x>=w/1.06) && (y>=h/100)){
               // the function with the name 
             black(as);

         }


        // Below border
        if((x>w/23)&&(y>h/1.05)){

              // the function with the name 
          black(as);
        }


    }

for(var pixel of img.values()){

    var x=pixel.getX();
    var y=pixel.getY();
    var w=img.getWidth();
    var h=img.getHeight();

 border();

}

print(img);


  [1]: http://%20https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com//course1/example/index.php
```